# Issue restarting a Windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Hi I made some changes in a windows service coding side(some class files related to that),,means i did coding to fetch version value from registry in that class files,,,,After

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i got the mistake,,What actually i was doing is i am copying DLL created in the debug mode  and copying into the Installer path..Actually what i need is i have to copy DLL obtained from the release mode and copy into the installer side

Answer (score 0):

Your OnStart method is most probably hanging. Did you recently add any of that threading/timer code.

Is your tracer logging any information?
Can you write some debug code to log where you are getting to and what exceptions are being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like `OnStart` is throwing an exception (in `SpoER.Init()`?, and it has permissions problem as well), this is causing the service to try and stop straight away.

I would suggest following the exception information you have given to try and locate the problem. It would be even better to move the bulk of this code into a separate class so you can write a console app which shares the same code as the service. By using the console app you can easily debug it.